# Haskell Attoparsec infinite loop

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

The code is based on `Haskell Attoparsec`, and when I use `parseOnly pString "v"`, it gives me the right answer as `Right (DontNeedTrim, "v")`.

While when I use the instruction `parseOnly (many' pString) "v"`, it seems drops into the `infinite loop` and finally failed with the overflowed stack.

```
data Signal = NeedTrim
              | DontNeedTrim
              deriving (Show)

pString :: Parser (Signal, [Char])
pString = ((char '\"' *> many' pChar' <* char '\"') >>= \s -> return (NeedTrim, s))
          <|> (many' pChar >>= \s -> return (DontNeedTrim, s))

pChar :: Parser Char
pChar = char '\\' *> (pEscape <|> spaces *> endOfLine *> pChar)
        <|> satisfy (`C.notElem` "\"\\\n#;")

pChar' :: Parser Char
pChar' = char '\\' *> pEscape
         <|> satisfy (`C.notElem` "\\\"")

pEscape :: Parser Char
pEscape = choice (zipWith decode "bnt\\\"" "\b\n\t\\\"")
  where decode c r = r <$ char c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second alternative in `pString` accepts the empty string: `many' pChar >>= \s -> return (...)`. Thus `many' pString` keeps consuming the empty string ad infinitum.

Comment: It completely solves the problem. :) And is it means that after consuming "v", it keeps consuming empty string for input "v"?